# Метод для парсинга переменных при изменении любой из них

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть три InputField. Значения, находящиеся в них, должны конвертироваться в float. Я могу сделать метод CheckChange в скриптах, где используются эти значения и переводить из string в float, но хотелось бы сделать один метод для конвертации из string в float при изменении любой переменной. Но не могу сообразить, как это сделать

У меня был такой код для каждой переменной string в скриптах, где использовались int овые переменные

```
/* public void CheckChangeSpawnTime()
{
   // _spawnPeriodString = UI.InputFieldsObject.GetComponent<UI>().InputFieldSpawnTime.text;
    _spawnPeriod = int.Parse(_spawnPeriodString);
    Debug.Log(_spawnPeriod);
}
```

*/

И вот такой код для инициализации InputField

```
public static GameObject InputFieldsObject;
/*public InputField InputFieldSpeed;
public InputField InputFieldDistance;
public InputField InputFieldSpawnTime;
*/

private void Start()
{
    InputFieldsObject = gameObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое:

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class Input : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField _inputField;

    public float FloatValue => float.Parse(_inputField.text);
}
```

При каждом обращении к FloatValue будет парситься значение из поля и возвращаться.

Если нужно только при изменении менять значение, у inputfield существует ивент onValueChanged:

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class Input : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField _inputField;

    public float FloatValue { get; private set; }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(Parse);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _inputField.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(Parse);
    }

    private void Parse(string input)
    {
        FloatValue = float.Parse(input);
    }
}
```

Либо, есть ивент onEndEdit, который вызывается, когда пользователь заканчивает вводить данные(нажимает enter или кликает вне поля)

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class Input : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField _inputField;

    public float FloatValue { get; private set; }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(Parse);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _inputField.onEndEdit.RemoveListener(Parse);
    }

    private void Parse(string input)
    {
        FloatValue = float.Parse(input);
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace DefaultNamespace
{
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Input _input;

        private void Update()
        {
            if (UnityEngine.Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Debug.Log(_input.FloatValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем здесь свойства? Никак не понимаю их пользу и зачем их абсолютно везде пихают. А код не работает. Или я что то не так сделала. Тут, как я понимаю, для одного ИФ сделано. А у меня их три. Также вопрос - зачем здесь ТМР

Comment: Так а как ты сделала то, что именно не работает, я гадать должен? Залей куда-нибудь свой код, на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), например. У меня всё работает. А что вместо свойств использовать? Поля? Поле может быть либо только паблик, либо только приватным, используя свойство, я могу сделать его доступным только для чтения извне, что, собственно, здесь и происходит. Только для чтения его делают, чтобы невозможно было изменить данные извне и предотвратить неожиданное поведение.

Comment: Дополнила вопрос. Код в вопросе

Comment: @Helena Во-первых, твой InputFieldsObject может быть не обычным GameObject, тем типом, который тебе нужен, то есть UI, соответственно, геткомпонент не нужен будет. Во-вторых, перевод из текста в инт, не ответственность компонента, который использует этот инт, это должен делать компонент с инпут филдами, а тот, кому нужен инт, должен получать инт, а не текст. Да и синглтон здесь не нужен, ты можешь передать через serializefield нужный компонент. Сейчас дополню ответ тем, как использовать.

Comment: @Helena Если несколько инпут филдов, делаешь несколько свойств

Comment: А без свойств нельзя? Как уже сказала - я не понимаю, для чего они нужны. То же самое можно с помощью полей делать, а свойства только усложняют чтение кода

Comment: @Helena Не нужны свойства, замени их полями, в чем проблема? Я лишь показал пример, изменяй так как тебе удобно, позже поймешь что лучше, а что хуже.